# getResourceAsStream not able to pickup up xml files?

Tags: java, maven, resources

`InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xml/ruleSet.xml");`

the resourceAsStream here comes as null,
I have configured the resource path in pom too:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

and I am trying to read the ruleset.xml from:

```
src
 -- org
 -- xml -> This folder contains ruleset xml
```

I have even tried keeping the ruleset.xml file inside the same package where the class is, but still it returns null.

Did I configure something wrong or miss something here?

Comment: try `InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/xml/ruleSet.xml");` (note the slash)

Comment: remove the above configuration for resources just keep the files in the default location src/main/resources and then it should work...

Comment: There are other files such as build.properties, so I cannot remove the above configuration.

Comment: @khmarbaise Your solution worked. I have not removed the above config, but added :

      `<resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resource</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>`

Comment: You should follow convention over configuration...makes life easier...

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this.

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
         <includes>
             <include>**/*.xml</include>
          </includes>
 </resource>
```

Comment: I dont have src/main/java as my structure

Comment: Can you provide an image of your structure ? Are you able to build the application using mvn clean install command ?

Comment: If possible, can you provide the complete pom.xml so that I can help you.